# Predicting with lmer: errors and missing p-values

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

In an experiment, female fish were exposed to two levels of photoperiod (Ambient & Compressed), two levels of temperature (4 & 7). They were in four tanks (two tanks for each photoperiod, one tank for each temperature within photoperiod). There were nine samplings denoted by time_date in the data. Among other responses is "k". My interest is on the effects of photoperiod, temperature and time_date on "k".
Challenges faced: Unbalanced design (one photoperiod or temperature level not sampled during a sampling), pseudo-replication (each tank is a treatment (temperature masked within photoperiod)). with some reading, I came across the mixed models. I have tried with lmer (more importantly: I am not sure if am right) and fell into warnings and outputs with no p-values. I appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Here is the sample data

```
fem.fish <- structure(list(time_date = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("30-Jan-18", 
"11-Apr-18", "13-Jun-18", "07-Aug-18", "19-Sep-18", "30-Oct-18", 
"28-Nov-18", "03-Jan-19", "17-Jan-19", "31-Jan-19", "14-Feb-19", 
"28-Feb-19", "14-Mar-19", "27-Mar-19", "10-Apr-19", "24-Apr-19"
), class = "factor"), photo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Ambient", 
"Compress"), class = "factor"), temp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("4", 
"7"), class = "factor"), tank = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", 
"T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), k = c(5.041791145, 5.408503999, 
5.535282299, 5.346402317, 5.376649977, 5.072021484, 6.097412109, 
4.390658006, 5.13676712, 4.472827193, 5.381892125, 4.882544582, 
4.655393586, 5.435528121, 4.985185185, 4.548431822, 5.041791145, 
5.408503999, 5.535282299, 5.346402317, 5.376649977, 5.072021484, 
6.097412109, 4.390658006, 5.13676712, 4.472827193, 5.381892125, 
4.882544582, 4.655393586, 5.435528121, 4.985185185, 4.548431822, 
5.517125816, 4.772205603, 5.928149807, 4.152323266, 4.666037968, 
4.638984928, 4.044444444, 4.720296599, 5.315500686, 4.967790359, 
3.520804755, 4.722326417, 5.051895044, 4.807450844, 5.096461818, 
5.28703008, 5.653368614, 6.357164944, 3.979492188, 3.928861374, 
5.632685221, 5.264668498, 5.281464786, 5.387205387, 4.332381668, 
5.250388878, 4.580237638, 4.650926114, 5.65951009, 4.401587625, 
5.194587481, 4.184813255, 4.44738449, 5.829977261, 4.331985587, 
4.827988338, 4.022222222, 3.672891297, 5.148148148, 4.068381688, 
5.71922963, 4.566763848, 5.330442907, 2.422536369, 5.346580575, 
4.971865289, 5.018922289, 5.513702624, 4.432146456, 5.692296224, 
4.738120151, 4.896057489, 5.50365439, 5.249023438, 5.737818961, 
4.260276996, 5.242507722, 4.580758017, 5.021888504, 5.013662642, 
4.308286338, 5.50840192, 4.732342764, 4.672289386, 5.715557782, 
3.827088497, 4.632069971, 4.935541824, 4.008746356, 4.963859809, 
4.836806618, 4.46244856, 4.839677641, 4.498269896, 4.88357943, 
4.984069185, 4.596844478, 5.196200195, 5.165529005, 14.74622771, 
5.397084548, 7.983198678, 5.691090246, 5.707491082, 5.187172012, 
6.297376093, 4.647178889, 4.282407407, 4.333496094, 4.773656052, 
4.770999725, 4.092207407, 3.917638484, 5.193905817, 3.704833984, 
5.571239611, 4.226680384, 3.65230095, 4.78515625, 5.603027344, 
4.159218067, 4.719370009, 4.437016946, 4.407713499, 4.284050303, 
4.676783265, 4.311689337, 4.540625, 4.864470022, 4.668176455, 
5.221193416, 4.997084123, 4.112752873, 5.587217586, 6.045051626, 
4.605417744, 4.35030714, 5.185252617, 4.752696927, 4.446670562, 
4.268256569, 4.30372087, 4.025205761, 5.696474074, 4.068342788, 
3.5212701, 4.544646911, 5.212620027, 5.31978738, 4.879910442, 
4.606482493, 4.33502906, 5.294067215, 5.770262391, 4.264308136, 
4.501028807, 2.944958848, 4.180638577, 4.120435057, 3.833076111, 
4.496793003, 4.232167131, 3.783896334, 5.070553936, 4.825776352, 
4.643534043, 6.318587106, 5.66205358, 5.194631597, 4.72557037, 
4.195096521, 4.956238551, 3.503093444, 5.24857851, 4.792524005, 
4.44229595, 5.285131195, 4.335878892, 4.170953361, 4.045779268
)), row.names = c(NA, -192L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I tried and the first warning

```
    fit1 <- lmer(k ~ 0 + photo*temp*time_date + (1|tank), data = fem.fish, REML = FALSE)

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 12 columns / coefficients
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

My summary and another warning on correlation matrix

```
summary(fit1)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: k ~ 0 + photo * temp * time_date + (1 | tank)
   Data: fem.fish

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   551.2    635.9   -249.6    499.2      166 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.7467 -0.4380 -0.0447  0.3663  9.7226 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 tank     (Intercept) 0.0000   0.0000  
 Residual             0.7883   0.8879  
Number of obs: 192, groups:  tank, 4

Fixed effects:
                                         Estimate Std. Error t value
photoAmbient                            5.284e+00  3.139e-01  16.832
photoCompress                           4.937e+00  3.139e-01  15.728
temp7                                  -1.218e-14  4.439e-01   0.000
time_date17-Jan-19                     -9.116e-02  4.439e-01  -0.205
time_date31-Jan-19                     -9.798e-02  4.439e-01  -0.221
time_date14-Feb-19                      1.264e-01  4.439e-01   0.285
time_date28-Feb-19                     -3.986e-01  4.439e-01  -0.898
time_date14-Mar-19                      3.655e-01  4.439e-01   0.823
time_date27-Mar-19                     -3.979e-01  4.439e-01  -0.896
time_date10-Apr-19                     -4.122e-01  4.439e-01  -0.929
time_date24-Apr-19                     -2.184e-01  4.439e-01  -0.492
photoCompress:temp7                     8.874e-15  6.278e-01   0.000
photoCompress:time_date31-Jan-19       -2.957e-01  6.278e-01  -0.471
photoCompress:time_date28-Feb-19        1.575e+00  6.278e-01   2.509
photoCompress:time_date14-Mar-19       -6.073e-01  6.278e-01  -0.967
temp7:time_date17-Jan-19               -4.121e-02  6.278e-01  -0.066
temp7:time_date31-Jan-19                2.382e-01  6.278e-01   0.379
temp7:time_date14-Feb-19               -2.024e-01  6.278e-01  -0.322
temp7:time_date28-Feb-19               -1.441e+00  6.278e-01  -2.295
temp7:time_date14-Mar-19               -1.104e+00  6.278e-01  -1.759
temp7:time_date27-Mar-19               -4.306e-01  6.278e-01  -0.686
temp7:time_date10-Apr-19               -7.885e-01  6.278e-01  -1.256
temp7:time_date24-Apr-19               -5.872e-01  6.278e-01  -0.935
photoCompress:temp7:time_date14-Mar-19  9.077e-01  8.879e-01   1.022

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 24 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

fit warnings:
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 12 columns / coefficients
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

My understanding on t-values is not good at all, so I cannot establish whether there are significant effects or even whether the interactions are significant or not.

I will appreciate your suggestions on the modelling (Fitting the right model?) and more of what you find useful

Thank you so much all.

Comment: you can use some package to calculate a pvalue... but.. as you can see from the error, you don't have enough observations to fit that complicated model.. Are you sure about doing this? Like is this model ```lmer(k ~ 0 + photo*temp*time_date + (1|tank)``` justified?

Comment: Is there a reason you have eliminated the intercept (specifying 0+ at the start?). You are running into a few issues. One is that you have certain levels of predictors which perfectly align, leading to the rank deficiency warning. This means that there are levels of your predictors not making it into the model. Mixed-models don't have p-values by default, and generally it is recommended to compare two nested models with a likelihood ratio test

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. About the model being justified or not, I just tried it after doing some reading (So I am totally new to these models - If there is a better suggestion on how to - I can also give it a thought). I have tried lmertest, now I can see p-values. I have removed the zero, actually I had no reason putting it (Thanks very much). And now I am trying to go through the likelihood ratio test - Hopefully I will get a solution through it - however, welcome are suggestions for the probably better approaches. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your data for the following example. I think due to the fact that all your terms are categorical, you get the rank deficient model. I'd suggest you use time as continuous predictor, thereby you get rid of the rank-deficiency warning.

```r
library(lme4)
library(parameters)
library(performance)

levels(fem.fish$time_date) <- 1:nlevels(fem.fish$time_date)
fem.fish$time_date <- as.numeric(fem.fish$time_date)

fit1 <- lmer(
  k ~ 1 + photo * temp * time_date + (1 | tank),
  data = fem.fish,
  REML = FALSE
)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

The second warning about the singular fit (now the first, and only warning) is because you literally have no variability in your outcome across the different groups (indicated by `tank`). This means that the random effects model here gives you not much more benefit than a simple linear model.

```r
ranef(fit1)
#> $tank
#>    (Intercept)
#> T1           0
#> T2           0
#> T3           0
#> T4           0
#> 
#> with conditional variances for "tank"
```

Finally, you could use the packages [parameters](https://easystats.github.io/parameters) and [performance](https://easystats.github.io/performance) to get comprehensive model summaries (including different p-value approximations like Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger, standardized parameters or (cluster) robust standard errors) or model fit indices (like r2).

```r
parameters::model_parameters(fit1)
#> Parameter                                 | Coefficient |   SE |        95% CI |     t |  df |      p
#> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)                               |        5.56 | 0.61 | [ 4.36, 6.76] |  9.06 | 182 | < .001
#> photo [Compress]                          |       -1.46 | 1.04 | [-3.50, 0.58] | -1.41 | 182 | 0.160 
#> temp [7]                                  |        0.69 | 0.94 | [-1.16, 2.53] |  0.73 | 182 | 0.467 
#> time_date                                 |       -0.04 | 0.05 | [-0.13, 0.06] | -0.74 | 182 | 0.461 
#> photo [Compress] * temp [7]               |        0.73 | 1.52 | [-2.24, 3.70] |  0.48 | 182 | 0.631 
#> photo [Compress] * time_date              |        0.12 | 0.09 | [-0.06, 0.31] |  1.35 | 182 | 0.178 
#> temp [7] * time_date                      |       -0.09 | 0.07 | [-0.23, 0.05] | -1.29 | 182 | 0.198 
#> (photo [Compress] * temp [7]) * time_date |       -0.07 | 0.13 | [-0.33, 0.19] | -0.52 | 182 | 0.604

performance::r2(fit1)
#> Warning: Can't compute random effect variances. Some variance components equal zero.
#>   Solution: Respecify random structure!
#> Random effect variances not available. Returned R2 does not account for random effects.
#> # R2 for Mixed Models
#> 
#>   Conditional R2: NA
#>      Marginal R2: 0.088
```

Now that your time variable is continuous, you may think about a non-linear relationship of the time trend. You could use the *spline* package to model this, and [ggeffects](http://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects) to get effects plots. This works, of course, for the model with linear time trend as well as other curvilinear time trends.

```r
library(ggeffects)
pr <- ggpredict(fit1, c("time_date", "photo", "temp"))
plot(pr)
```

[image]

```r
library(splines)
fit2 <- lmer(
  k ~ 1 + photo * temp * bs(time_date) + (1 | tank),
  data = fem.fish,
  REML = FALSE
)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

pr <- ggpredict(fit2, c("time_date [all]", "photo", "temp"))
plot(pr)
```

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel , sure it does!

Answer (score 2):

Try to import the "lmerTtest" package.

Before fit your model import this package, in this way you will see the p-value and the "*" of significance:

```
library("lme4")
library("lmerTest")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have done it, now I can see them.

Comment: Nice!, so please could you mark the answer as usefull. Thanks